# Header files verses Libraries

Tags: c, header, libraries

I know their are many differences between header files and libraries but is it safe to say that libraries contain compilable code and header files do not?

Comment: The simple statement I would make is that libraries contain *compiled* code and that header files contain declarations.

Comment: Header files are source files, libraries contain object files. Typically, the header file contains the declarations of the functions in the corresponding object files.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries contain *compiled* object code (not "compilable code" - that would be a .c file).  A library is a packaged collection of of object modules.

Headers (generally) contain declarative source code - they allow separate compilation and linking by giving the compiler visibility of the data types and signatures of functions and data defined in other object code to be linked - either from libraries or individual compiled source (object) modules.

I say generally because `#include` is not part of the C language, but rather a pre-processor directive (as is any line starting `#` in C). The pre-processor inserts the content of a `#include`'ed file before passing it to the compiler itself, so in fact it could contain any valid code, but that often causes issues when linking with other code that may have also included the same header.

It is not a matter of "libraries vs headers" since they serve entirely different purposes and are involved in different ends of the in the pre-process -> compile -> link process. A library will generally have an associated header file containing the declarations of its public (external) interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

> is it safe to say that libraries contain compilable code and header files do not?

Not really.

You would need to differentiate between two different library formats:

- **static / dynamic libraries**: these libraries have already been compiled, they don't contain compilable code.
- **source code libraries**: these libraries contain source code that needs to be compiled.

Within the source code library category, you could find all sorts of formats / designs - not least of which is the **single-file header library**.

There are many [single header libraries](https://github.com/nothings/single_file_libs) out in the wild. **These header libraries will contain (or produce) code**.